# Iterating over states doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have an item with multiple `StateGroup`s:

`MyObject.qml`

```
    import QtQuick 2.0

    Item
    {
        id: root

        property alias myStates: myStateGroup.states

        // ..

        StateGroup
        {
            id: myStateGroup
            states:
            [
                State
                {
                    name: "first"
                },
                State
                {
                    name: "second"
                },
                State
                {
                    name: "third"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I want to iterate over the state names: (in another file)

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    for (var i in instance.myStates)
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(i))
        console.log(i.name)
        //....
    }
}
```

What I get is

```
"0"
undefined
"1"
undefined
"2"
undefined
```

I want to iterate over the names of the states. What am I doing wrong that I get integers instead of `State`s?
I know I could use a simple C-like for, but this looks really awful. I'd like to use the `for ... in` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    for (var i in instance.myStates)
    {
        console.log(instance.myStates[i].name)
    }
}
```

[for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) puts in i array item property name value. In this case it's just integer number.